# Is there a way to create bookmark on Pantheon Files using terminal?

Tags: pantheon-files, pantheon-terminal

I wonder if there's a way to add a bookmark in Pantheon Files (same as CTRL+D) using some command in terminal?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest way I can think of is to write the location that you want to bookmark to the bookmarks file, for example:

```
echo "file:///home/user/location Place" >> ~/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks
```

Of course, replacing the location string `/home/user/location` with your desired location and `Place` with whatever you want to call the bookmark.